# Ubuntu 18.04, deja-dup, Backend

Tags: deja-dup, duplicity

I have Ubuntu 18.04, and use deja-dup for making a backup of my folders into an external disk. I have the error:

```
BackendException: Could not initialize backend: No module named gi.repository
```

and no backup is done.

Deja-dup was working under Ubuntu 18.04 normally for some time, I think it stopped because of some automatic updates.

I have tried `sudo apt install python-gi` and `sudo apt install duplicity`, but the error persists.

I suspect it is a problem in duplicity linked to Python libraries it doesn't find. Is there some advice to give regarding this error by the community?

Comment: maybe python3 libs are missing. try `sudo apt install python3-gi`

Comment: It is already installed "python3-gi is already the newest version (3.26.1-2ubuntu1)".